# Validation failed: Video Paperclip::Errors::NotIdentifiedByImageMagickError

Tags: ffmpeg, paperclip, delayed-paperclip

I have a model with an attached video. I want to create a scaled version of the video along with a series of thumbnails. I have the following setup:

```
has_attached_file :video,
    styles: {
        original: { format: 'mp4', processors: [:transcoder] },
        large: { geometry: "720x720", format: 'jpg', processors: [:thumbnail] },
        medium: { geometry: "540x540", format: 'jpg', processors: [:thumbnail] },
        thumb: { geometry: "180x180", format: 'jpg', processors: [:thumbnail] }
    },
    default_url: ""
```

When I test this in my development environment it works perfectly. The video and all images are correctly sized. When I deploy to Heroku however, I get the following error:

```
Validation failed: Video Paperclip::Errors::NotIdentifiedByImageMagickError
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.2/lib/active_record/validations.rb:78:in `raise_validation_error'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.2/lib/active_record/validations.rb:50:in `save!'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.2/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/dirty.rb:30:in `save!'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.2/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:324:in `block in save!'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.2/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:395:in `block in with_transaction_returning_status'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:232:in `block in transaction'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/transaction.rb:189:in `within_new_transaction'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:232:in `transaction'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.2/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:211:in `transaction'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.2/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:392:in `with_transaction_returning_status'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.2/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:324:in `save!'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.2/lib/active_record/suppressor.rb:45:in `save!'
/app/app/models/concerns/snapshot_methods.rb:37:in `copy_from_ziggeo!'
/app/app/workers/snapshot_transcoder.rb:16:in `perform'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/resque-status-0.5.0/lib/resque/plugins/status.rb:161:in `safe_perform!'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/resque-status-0.5.0/lib/resque/plugins/status.rb:137:in `perform'
```

What am I missing here? I've searched for `NotIdentifiedByImageMagickError` and scanned numerous other questions on this issue, but have not had any success fixing my problem.

Most of the solutions I've seen involve setting `Paperclip.options[:command_path] = "/usr/bin/identify"` in development. Since my problem is only on production, I tried applying this to production, subbing in the correct path for my production environment, like so:

```
Paperclip.options[:command_path] = "/app/vender/imagemagick/bin/identify"
```

This had no effect. Neither did `/app/vender/imagemagick/bin`.

Answer (score 0):

After much head-banging I managed to solve this by purging my app's cache and re-installing ImageMagick. Here are the steps I took:

1. Install the [heroku-repo CLI](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-repo#purge_cache) and run `heroku repo:purge_cache -a APP_NAME`.
2. Create an empty commit: `git commit --allow-empty -m "Hope this works"`
3. Redeploy to Heroku: `git push heroku master`

Redeploying takes several minutes since Heroku now has to rebuild all your static assets and dependencies from scratch.

From what I understand, this problem is somehow caused by a faulty cached copy of ImageMagick. I'll happily accept the answer of anyone who can provide a more informed explanation for what caused this issue. Even though it's solved for now, I'm not convinced that this won't just happen again at some random point in the future.